# Accessing org.eclipse.swt widgets from C/C++

Tags: c++, widget, swt

Does anyone know of an example for accessing org.eclipse.swt widgets from C/C++.

I'm guessing that SelectionEvent handling will also be required as well as just being able to display the widgets.

I'm not a Java user so while I have heard of APIs like JNI I don't know anything about them or if this is even possible.

Thanks very much,
john

Comment: What do you want to do with that?? If you simply want to make an interface in C++, use Qt or something.

Comment: Thanks  Guillaume, I've used Qt and wxWidgets for many years but the dials, sliders knobs etc just don't cut it compared to those in swt.Maybe I should look at some of the addon libraries for Qt/wxW.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really possible. Since Java code runs in a JVM you C++ code would have to start up a JVM and then try and communicate with it.

JNI is for calling C or C++ code from Java which is more straightforward.

Comment: Thanks very much, Greg, that is a shame but  I appreciate the feedback. All the best,